# Como mostar apenas os número de um cpf

Tags: html

Bom a questão pede que leia um cpf, e mostre ele sem os pontos, tentei fazer utilizando uma lógica de C, porém o javascript acho que não possui isso, o que eu tenho que alterar para ter o resultado

Meu html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>questao07</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="cpf" type="text">
    <button onclick="sem()">Clique para mostar sem os pontos</button>
    <button onclick="com()">Clique para mostar com os pontos</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu javascript

```
function sem(argument) {
   var nome = document.getElementById('cpf').value;
   for(var i=0;i<nome.length;i++)
   {
      if (nome[i].CharAt>=0&&nome[i].CharAt<=9) {
        console.log(nome[i].CharAt);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É sempre importante percebermos o erros que cometemos de forma a evoluirmos. Neste sentido o seu caso o código até ficou perto de ficar a funcionar.

O maior problema foi o `nome[i].CharAt` que não está correto e é como se tivesse a tentar fazer as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo. Somente `nome[i]` já lhe obtem uma string que representa a letra na posição `i` e o mesmo vale para `nome.charAt(i)`, agora não pode usar os dois em simultâneo. Como o resultado é uma letra também não pode comparar com um numero `>=0`, mas consegue faze-lo na forma de `string`

Veja como corrigindo esses dois pontos já obtem um resultado perto do que esperava:

```js
function sem(argument) {
   var nome = document.getElementById('cpf').value;

   for(var i=0;i<nome.length;i++)
   {
      if (nome[i] >= '0' && nome[i] <= '9') {
        console.log(nome[i]);
      }
   }
}

sem();
```

```html
<input id="cpf" value="340.905.290-93">
```

Apesar de já funcionar, o `console.log` foi feito digito a digito acabando por não ser tornar muito util. Melhor seria retornar o valor construido, que consegue fazer se for acumulando cada digito que interpreta da string original:

```js
function sem(argument) {
   var nome = document.getElementById('cpf').value;
   var cpfSemPontos = ""; //nova variavel para ir acumulado os digitos

   for(var i=0;i<nome.length;i++)
   {
      if (nome[i] >= '0' && nome[i] <= '9') {
        cpfSemPontos += nome[i]; //concatena o novo digito
      }
   }
   return cpfSemPontos; //devolve no fim
}

cpfSemPontos = sem();
console.log(cpfSemPontos);
```

```html
<input id="cpf" value="340.905.290-93">
```

Note que não está a a utilizar o parametro que definiu na função, e que eu não removi propositadamente, mas é algo que deve remover. Não deixe coisas no código que não utiliza, pois isso dificulta a legibilidade e acaba por confundir qualquer pessoa que leia o código. Mais util seria até receber o id do `<input>` que quer interpretar o cpf e dessa forma conseguia utilizar a função para obter um cpf sem números de qualquer campo.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar algo mais simples, um *regular expression* que procurar tudo o que não forem dígitos e remova, usando a função `replace`:

```js
var cpf = "123.456.789-00";
var cpr_sonumeros = cpf.replace(/\D/g,'');

console.log(cpr_sonumeros);
```

Enquanto `\d` localiza só dígitos (d mínusculo), o `\D` é contrário (D maiúsculo), não-dígitos, que é o que queremos aqui, para removê-los. O `g` significa "global", ou seja, vai pesquisar em toda o valor da variável `cpf`.